# NDepend find private methods without documentation

Tags: c#, xml-documentation, ndepend, cqlinq

i'm new to ndepend and i want a cqlinq rule to find all not documented methods. Thats my current query, but there is no documented-Property.

```
from m in Application.Methods 
.Where(m => !m.IsGeneratedByCompiler && m.Visibility == Visibility.Private && m.??Documentation?? == false)

select new { m, m.Visibility }
```

any ideas? Happy new year... :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about this code query?

```
from m in JustMyCode.Methods
where m.IsPrivate
&& m.NbLinesOfCode > 5 // Adjust to your needs
&& m.NbLinesOfComment == 0
select new { m, m.NbLinesOfCode }
```

[image: Match non commented private methods with ndepend]

Comment: Hey Patrick, thanks for your answer, but i was talking about documentation above methods, not about comments in the methods. so i actually want all private methods, that have a xml summary documentation missing...

Comment: Indeed, as explained by email we'll support documentation within an upcoming version